# ¿Por qué mi codigo en jsfiddle no compila?

Tags: jsfiddle

Soy nuevo en esto de jsfiddle, realicé un [holamundo](https://jsfiddle.net/emeery/qjg4p1dy/) en React de lo mas sencillo pero no se ejecuta, ¿A qué se debe este error?, tomé el ejemplo de este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/) ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?, el código es idéntico pero no imprime el resultado. Me podrían ayudar.

Comment: si no muestras lo que has intentado no podemos ayudarte sin saber el error. puedes editar la pregunta y colocar tu codigo?

Comment: Te puse la liga de el archivo jsfiddle Santiago, donde se encuentra 'holamundo'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comprueba que has elegido los mismos External Resources:

- react.development.js
- react-dom.development.js

A mí me pasó lo mismo con AngularJS

**Tu proyecto**

[image]

**Cómo deberías tener el proyecto**

[image]

Comment: Te agaradezco por el comentario, ya por fin me quedo. Gracias a todos por el apoyo, a seguirle dando

Answer (score 1):

Como dicen en las respuestas anteriores te faltan las extensiones externas y cambiar la ventana de JS por BABEL + JSX, ademas estas haciendo mal el `render()` el contenido va dentro de llaves `render(){/* contenido */}` y debes realizar el `return`, y en el `ReactDOM.render()` tienes la sintaxis erronea de tal manera que lo haces asi `React.DOM`.

Answer (score 0):

Te faltan los external resources en el JsFiddle, en otras palabras los recursos externos. Sin eso no te va a funcionar el ejemplo.

Puedes agregarlos en las pestañas de la izquierda External Resources, o directamente desde el código haces referencia a ellos.

https://unpkg.com/react@16.2.0/umd/react.development.js

https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js

JsFuncionando

https://jsfiddle.net/qjg4p1dy/33/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora bien el código que escribiste tiene varios errores por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acostumbrate a usar la consola, para poder revisar tu código. Yo utilizo Google Chrome.

Comment: me podrías decir cuales archivos externos, el hola mundo funcional tiene los mismos archivos que el mio. O donde irían? Te agradezco

Comment: Actualicé mi respuesta.