# ¿Cómo puedo importar un módulo de Javascript en JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Estoy tratando de importar la librería `brain.js` para correr uno de los ejemplos del sitio.

- Como no hallé la opción de importar el script como módulo en la interfaz, intenté llamar al librería desde la parte para el html y agregarle `type="module"` y activar el flag de mi navegador como dice en esta [respuesta de SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415925/4585308)

  obtengo el mensaje de error

> SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module

Y específicamente en JSFiddle obtengo el mensaje de error adicional

> ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable brain

```js
import brain from 'brain.min.js';

const trainingData = [
  'Jane saw Doug.',
  'Doug saw Jane.',
  'Spot saw Doug and Jane looking at each other.',
  'It was love at first sight, and Spot had a frontrow seat. It was a very special moment for all.'
];

const lstm = new brain.recurrent.LSTM();
const result = lstm.train(trainingData, {
  iterations: 1500
});
const run1 = lstm.run('Jane');
const run2 = lstm.run('Doug');
const run3 = lstm.run('Spot');
const run4 = lstm.run('It');

console.log('run 1: Jane' + run1);
console.log('run 2: Doug' + run2);
console.log('run 3: Spot' + run3);
console.log('run 4: It' + run4);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brain/0.6.3/brain.min.js" type="module"></script>
```

¿Cómo puedo importar la librería para hacer que el ejemplo corra en el JSFiddle?

Comment: Esta pregunta se soluciona de manera muy similar a la solución que dí justo en esta otra pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/126103/por-qu%C3%A9-mi-codigo-en-jsfiddle-no-compila/126106#126106

Comment: @CynthS.B. y entonces cuál es la solución según tú? :)

Comment: Te he puesto el enlace en el comentario. Entra y sigue las instrucciones. ;)

Comment: No lo veo podrías ponerlo como respuesta?

Comment: el import solo sirve si tienes dentro de la carpeta de la pagina la libreria en tu caso `brain.js` si quieres usar una librería en jsfiddle tendrás que usar un link a esa librería

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al importar tu script:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/brain/0.6.3/brain.min.js"></script>
```

Se asocia el objeto `brain` al objeto `window`. Crea una constante con el objeto y ya lo tienes accesible:

```
const brain = window.brain;
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/gk4xt8tx/)

[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877904/how-do-you-import-a-javascript-package-from-a-cdn-script-tag-in-react)